# Why can't I use printf with sqlite when executed in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, printf

Per [this page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html), `printf` belongs to the core functions of sqlite, so, with the `sqlite3` shell, I can execute this statement successfully:

```
sqlite> create table foo as select printf("%5.2f", 42.424242) bar;
```

Yet, If I try to do what I believe is the same thing with a Python script, it errors with `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: printf`. Here's the script that I used:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys
import sqlite3

db_filename = 'printf.db'
if os.path.isfile(db_filename):
   os.remove(db_filename)

db = sqlite3.connect(db_filename)
db.text_factory = str

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute(r'create table foo as select printf("%5.2f", 42.424242) bar')
```

Does someone know why that is?

**Edit**: As per g4ur4v's suggestion, I changed `cur.execute('create...` in the script to `cur.execute(r'create...`. The error did not change.

Comment: can you try `cur.execute(r'create table foo as select printf("%5.2f", 42.424242) bar')`

Comment: I tried that and the error stays the same.

Comment: this might help https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2013-July/652876.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` was added as a core function in version 3.8.3 of `sqlite3`. Likely the Python you are using uses an older version. This information can be found in these [release notes](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html):

> 2014-02-03 (3.8.3)
>
> > Added support for common table expressions and the WITH clause.
> >
> > Added the **printf()** SQL function.

One way to check what version of the Sqlite3 library your Python is using is to issue this command:

```
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
```

Comment: What if you are stuck with something older?  Any workarounds?